# How to login ftp with user name and password from AIX 6.1?

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, aix

I want to develop a command line to login the ftp server with username & password. The script would be run on AIX 6.1, but now I was stuck.
I have searched on google and got some solutions, but no one works. See commands I have tried below:

```
    ftp ftp://username:password@server  
    ftp username:password@server  
    ftp server /user:username /password:password  
    ftp USER username PASS password
```

Could you please tell me the correct command?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a text file in your home directory named .netrc containing:

```
machine myserver.example.com login myusername password mypassword
```

However it would be more secure to set up ssl and use scp.  There's little reason to use an insecure protocol like ftp.

Comment: I believe the permissions for .netrc is fairly restrictive too so make it 600.